# Method of getting text on a windows form ( unmanaged C++ project )

Tags: c++, windows, forms, mfc, unmanaged

I'm in the process of learning C++. I've created a boilerplate Win32 app within VC++ 2008. I've studied through the code and am ready do do a bit of experimenting. I thought it would be cool to print all the windows messages received in the message loop to the form created via the boilerplate code. I for the life of me, can't figure out the method of getting text onto that form. I can't seem to identify and named object that I can use to reference that damn form. The best I can figure is I need to use the handle to reference the form somehow. Still, even if I did know how to reference the form, I'm not sure I know how I would create a label to display the text. Anyway, if someone could just point out what methodology I need to learn to make this happen it would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Donovan

Comment: Being a not great supporter of Microsoft, and especially MFC and Windows native API, I chose a different, easier GUI system:  wxWidgets.  Another popular GUI is Qt.  Bank your frustration now, it will only get worse as you get deeper into the **dark side**.

Comment: Plain Win32 API is *not* programmer friendly. Unless you really crave to know the gory details of a bad API, it's a good idea to use a good widget toolkit.

Comment: That's funny. I'm really not interested in Windows forms as an end result of my studies but not being able to display some simple text on a form has irked me. I will figure this out...

Comment: what kind of mfc app did you do? sdi,mdi or dialog based?

Comment: or are you speaking of c++/cli and .net forms?

Comment: Ehh, I'm not entirely sure. I simply fired up VC++ 2008 and selected Win32 as my project type. Anything else would have been default. I simply wanted to go through the boilerplate code and glean what I could from it.

Comment: maybe you then should remove the tag mfc and replace it with win32

Comment: The reason I tagged it with MFC is because this is my entry point definition: int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)

after looking up that function and investigating why it isn't WinMain I was lead to believe its MFC. Was I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you've created a label using resources, use its resource ID and

```
HWND *pWnd = ::GetDlgItem(mainDialogHwnd, IDC_YOUR_RESOURCE_ID);
::SetWindowText(pWnd, "Your Updated Text");
```

There are MFC equivalents for those too, should get you in the right direction.  Note that posting message loop means lots and lots of information... might not want to do that.  Check Spy++ if that's still available and in use today to see how many messages an app gets!

Comment: I guess if you overwrite the message every time it doesn't really matter, just as long as you aren't trying to write it all out and keep it all in a single window object... would consume a lot of memory very quickly

Comment: I noticed the boilerplate code doesn't store the handle for the main window into a global variable. Its only in scope for the creation of the window then gone. I figure I would need to know the handle globaly to make use of your example code right?

Comment: My last experience with VC++ was with VS 6, so I don't know what exactly the boilerplate code looks like unfortunately... but assuming it's a standard MFC project it probably creates a single, global CWinApp, and creates a CWnd somewhere... the function calls I used were old-style C WinAPI (which MFC wraps), you can get a pointer to an HWND by calling CWnd::GetSafeHwnd(), or you can find the equivalent MFC function for GetDlgItem and SetWindowText, they're probably similarly named, and wrapped in nice MFC classes.

Comment: For my code, you would do something like:

HWND *pMainWnd = mainApp.m_pMainWnd->GetSafeHwnd();
HWND *pCntrlWnd = ::GetDlgItem(pMainWnd, IDC_YOUR_RESOURCE_ID);
//use pCntrlWnd

Also you should be able to "bring in" a control into your main window class... from the resource editor right click the control and see if you can 'attach to class' or something, that should create a member variable of the class it's contained in, for instance a CEdit member variable for an edit control.

Comment: I think I see where I might be getting hung up. I'm using VC++ 2008 express. In the express edition you don't get to do resource editing. I would have to create the label by hand.